# Linux Container (LXC) image without vmlinux

Tags: boot, lxc, syslinux

Recently, I installed `lxc` and created an Ubuntu LXC image.

Then, I did `ls -a /` to see the directory listing of `/` inside the image.

To my surprise, there is no `vmlinux` or `vmlinuz` often seen in normal Linux distros.

My question, therefore, is: How can a LXC image be booted up without a vmlinux/z?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LXC are a bit different than "traditional" virtual machines.

Rather than emulating hardware they all use the same kernel (i.e. the kernel from your host).

From the [lxc introduction page](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/introduction/):

> LXC is a userspace interface for the Linux kernel containment features. Through a powerful API and simple tools, it lets Linux users easily create and manage system or application containers.

and more specifically (emphasis mine):

> LXC containers are often considered as something in the middle between a chroot and a full fledged virtual machine. The goal of LXC is to create an environment as close as possible to a standard Linux installation but **without the need for a separate kernel**.

Answer (score 1):

Containers are processes that run "in a bubble" with their own filesystem and network (among other things). They are not VMs. They use the kernel of their host (which is why they are much faster to start than a VM).

Comment: This is a very concise and exact answer. Thanks so much.